# Component attribute set by one method coming as null in second method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute, init

I am calling two functions in my lightning bundle init in the following order

```
helper.fetchAccountRequestAddressDetailsHelper(component, event, helper);
console.log('before fetch'+component.get("v.accountRequestSubmitted"));
```

Code for the helper methods

```
fetchAccountRequestAddressDetailsHelper : function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.getAccountRequestAddressDetails");
    action.setParams({
        accountRequestId : component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.c", response.getReturnValue());                
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

    fetchAccountRequestAddressDetailsFromAPIsHelper : function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.getAccountRequestAddressDetailsfromAPI");
    console.log('^^^^^12'+component.get("v.accountRequestSubmitted"));
    action.setParams({
        accountRequest : component.get("v.accountRequestSubmitted")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var accountRequest = response.getReturnValue(); 
            console.log('&&&&&&'+response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.accountRequestVerified", response.getReturnValue());                
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Here what is happening is that accountRequestSubmitted an attribute of the component is set in the first method. However, when I try to access it in my second method console.log('^^^^^12'+component.get("v.accountRequestSubmitted")); it is coming up as null. Am I making a mistake in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server-calls in lightning are performing [asynchronouly](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm).

> $A.enqueueAction(action) adds the server-side controller action to the
>   queue of actions to be executed. All actions that are enqueued will
>   run at the end of the event loop. Rather than sending a separate
>   request for each individual action, the framework processes the event
>   chain and batches the actions in the queue into one request. The
>   actions are asynchronous and have callbacks.

so if you want to do something after receive value it should be:

```
fetchAccountRequestAddressDetailsHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
    var cntrl = this;
    var action = component.get("c.getAccountRequestAddressDetails");
    action.setParams({
        accountRequestId : component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.c", response.getReturnValue());
            cntrl.fetchAccountRequestAddressDetailsFromAPIsHelper(component, event, helper);            
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

That means, that your callback function will execute later, when component will receive response from server controller.

by the way it is preferred to move logic to helper

Comment: This clears up my concept. Thank you very much. @AlexanderBerehovskiy